set_compute_unit_limit requires an unknown signer
   ix = process_item(
      {"lamports": int(lamports)}, 
      {
            "destination": destination_pk, 
            "from_account": from_account,
            "manager": manager.pubkey(), # signer
        }
    )
    
    #latest blockhash
    latest_blockhash = http_client.get_latest_blockhash(Confirmed).value
    hash = latest_blockhash.blockhash
    
    # Set up tx
    tx = Transaction(hash)
    
    # Add CU limit
    # cu_limit = set_compute_unit_limit(4000)
    # tx.add(cu_limit)
    
    tx.add(ix)
    
    #manager signed transaction
    signed_tx = manager_anchor_wallet.sign_transaction(tx)

    provider = Provider(async_client,manager_anchor_wallet)
    sig = await provider.send(signed_tx,TxOpts(preflight_commitment=Confirmed))

This works perfectly fine but as soon as I uncomment the code that adds the setting of limiting CU units, I get an error, SignerError: not enough signers
Why does this error occur and what's the missing signer needed to add CU limit?

To me, it's strange that it worked without the cu limit ix. Though, I can spot one thing that could be worth checking which is that provider.send does NOT work with signed_tx.

Woops typo in the code. Fixed it swith provider.send(signed_tx,.... And yes it does work without any issues if the I do not add cu_limit to tx. It's such a strange problem. I still have no idea why just this line causes this.

Adding a vote to close this as a duplicate since the other answer helped: Not enough signers when setting compute units

Figured it out thanks to this post.
Not enough signers when setting compute units
I needed to add the fee payer to the transaction.
tx.fee_payer = manager.pubkey()

